# Remove spans from html with a class but keep the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I had the following html:

```
<div id="main">
    This <span class="class-two">is</span> a <span class="class-one">string</span> and I want <span class="class-one">to remove</span> spans <span>with the</span> class class-one.
</div>
```

How would I remove all spans that have the class `class-one`?

The expected output from the above html would be:

```
<div id="main">
    This <span class="class-two">is</span> a string and I want to remove spans <span>with a</span> class
</div>
```

The class-two and the span without a class haven't been removed.

I also need to save the new html string into a variable which is the part I am struggling with.

Something like this:
`var html = $('#main').$('.class-one').replaceWith((i, txt) => txt);`

Answer (score 1):

Select `#main`, and find `.class-one`. Use [`.replaceWith()` with a function](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/#replaceWith-function) to replace with the text. Then use [`.end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/) to return to `.main` and get the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```js
const result = $('#main')
                   .find('.class-one')
                   .replaceWith((i, txt) => txt)
                   .end()
                   .html();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.class-one {
  color: red;
}

.class-two {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  This <span class="class-two">is</span> a <span class="class-one">string</span> and I want <span class="class-one">to remove</span> spans <span>with the</span> class class-one.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I have been doing but I can't work out how to save the contents of the replaceWith into a variable. I want it to get this type of thing `var html = $('#main').$('.class-one').replaceWith((i, txt) => txt);`. Obviously not that but hopefully that gives you an idea of what I am looking for.

Comment: Update the question with the code.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: That's done the trick thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome :)